# How to retrive 'X-PublicFolderMailbox' using soap ews

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

To route the requests to a public folder mailbox, you need to set the X-AnchorMailbox and X-PublicFolderMailbox headers to specific values returned by the Autodiscover service.

I have retrieved 'X-AnchorMailbox' value using the below soap call.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover"
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <a:RequestedServerVersion>Exchange2010</a:RequestedServerVersion>
        <wsa:Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettings</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:To>https://outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc</wsa:To>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <a:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover">
            <a:Request>
                <a:Users>
                    <a:User>
                        <a:Mailbox>%s</a:Mailbox>
                    </a:User>
                </a:Users>
                <a:RequestedSettings>
                    <a:Setting>PublicFolderInformation</a:Setting>
                </a:RequestedSettings>
            </a:Request>
        </a:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

> But I am not able to fetch X-PublicFolderMailbox using soap call.
>   Please help with xml schema and endpoint for request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use SOAP to get the X-PublicFolderMailbox value you need to make a POX (Plain old XML) auto-discover request against the Mailbox from the PublicFolderInformation eg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/requestschema/2006">
  <Request>
    <EMailAddress>SharedPublicFolder@contoso.com</EMailAddress>
    <AcceptableResponseSchema>http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a</AcceptableResponseSchema>
  </Request>
</Autodiscover>
```

and use the Server value from the response as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-hierarchy-requests?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have successfully fetched the value of X-PublicFolderMailbox.

Comment: But Now I am not able to create publicfolder using the above headers and CreateFolder.

Comment: Your creates must always be against the

Comment: master of the hierarchy

Comment: thanks. It is working now. Can we fetch public folders properties like who are the authorized users and what are their rights so that when we create public folder, we can restore these settings also?